# Wrongly spaced words in thesis title

Tags: titles

My problem relates to the "and graduation" part of the title below and would like more space between the two lines in the title. I'm using a template, could it be that that the "vertical space" between the lines was set in the thesis.cls file? If there is a quick/easy 'hack' to put in the preamble, that would also be appreciated.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{thesis}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter     
\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\center 


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics{UCT}
\end{center}
\textsc{\LARGE University of Cape Town}
\leavevmode
\\[1.5cm] 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\HRule \\[0.5cm]
{ \huge \bfseries The Determinants of Student Retention and Graduation}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} 
\large
\emph{Author:}\\
Christopher \textsc{Rooney}\\ % Your name
\href{mailto:chris.rooney1@gmail.com}{chris.rooney1@gmail.com}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{\fill}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} 
\large
\emph{Supervisor:} \\
Dr.\ Corn{\'e} \textsc{Van Walbeek}\\ %Supervisor's Name
\href{mailto:Cwalbeek@gmail.com}{Cwalbeek@gmail.com}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} \\ [2cm]
\begin{center}
  {\large A thesis submitted in partial fulfillment for the\par}
  {\large degree of Masters in Applied Economics (Development Stream) \par}
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{\Large \today \par}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You're missing `\par` after `Graduation`

Comment: Thanks @egreg! What is the difference between the \par command and \\? I tried the latter before posting here but it wasn't working.

Comment: You either have to place ``\\`` inside the braces or add `\par` before it, otherwise the setting of the `\baselineskip` for `\huge` will disappear before the paragraph is typeset. The initial `\center` should be `\centering`.